# Универсальный gson для разного формата дат

Tags: java, json, сериализация, gson

У меня есть класс, в котором есть поля `LocalDate` (yyyy-mm-dd) и в тоже время поля `LocalDateTime` (формата: "2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00").
(т.е. `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` и `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, если так понятнее)

Все решения, что я находил предлагают задать один из типов форматирования перед десериализацией. Но десериализация у меня происходит в обобщённом методе, где полученный json сразу форматируется в объект нужного типа строкой типа: 
`new Gson().fromJson(response.getBody(), type);`, где `Class <T> type`.

Полный пример метода:

```
public static <T> T get(String url, Class<T> type){
    try {
        HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest
                .get(ShikiConst.ROOT_API + url)
                .header("User-Agent", Client.getUserAgent())
                .asString();

        if (response.getStatus() != 200){
            ErrorStack.PushServerError(ShikiConst.ROOT_API + url, response.getStatus(), response.getStatusText());
            return null;
        }

        return new Gson().fromJson(response.getBody(), type); //ТА САМАЯ СТРОКА
    }
    catch (UnirestException | JsonSyntaxException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        ErrorStack.PushLocalError("QueryShell.get()", ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Поэтому хотелось бы как-то один раз задать gson, чтобы он мог распознать нужный формат и присвоить соответствующим полям в классе.

Comment: Вам нужно свою реализацию десериализации написать. В ней вы можете отталкиваясь от имени поля объекта парсить его разными способами. Код сам написать в ответ не могу - не делал ни разу, но могу ссылку с примером дать: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28325108/3212712

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае, я похожую задачу решил так (то есть похожую в том смысле, что в некоторых местах формат сериализованных дат был немножко разный)

Сначала создаем кастомный сериализатор/десериализатор даты:

```
public class DateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date>,JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    private static final String TAG=DateSerializer.class.getSimpleName();
    private final TimeZone utcTimeZone;
    private final DateFormat dateFormat;
    private final static String ISO_8601_FORMAT_STRING="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";

    public DateSerializer() {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_8601_FORMAT_STRING, Locale.ENGLISH);
        utcTimeZone=TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(utcTimeZone);
    }

    @Override public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

@Override
public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement,Type type,JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
    Date date;
    String[] alternateFormats={
            "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",
            "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS",
            "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    };
    String dateTimeString=jsonElement.getAsString();
    MyLogger.info(TAG, "Datetime="+dateTimeString);
    DateFormat alternateDateFormat;
    try {
        date=dateFormat.parse(dateTimeString);
        if(date!=null)
            return date;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //MyLogger.warning(TAG, "Error parsing="+dateTimeString+", format="+ISO_8601_FORMAT_STRING, e);
    }
    for(String alternateFormat:alternateFormats) {
        alternateDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(alternateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
        alternateDateFormat.setTimeZone(utcTimeZone);
        try {
            date = alternateDateFormat.parse(dateTimeString);
            if (date != null)
                return date;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error parsing="+dateTimeString+", format="+alternateFormat, ex);
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't parse date/time formatted as="+dateTimeString);
}    }
```

Далее встраиваем ее в gson:

```
gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateSerializer())
                .serializeNulls()
                //.setPrettyPrinting() //for debugging
                .disableHtmlEscaping() //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558709/gson-issue-with-string
                .create();
```

Comment: У вас, как я понял, принимает разные форматы и переводит в один. Мне же надо, чтобы поля LocalDate адекватно десериализовались в LocalData, а поля LocalDateTime адекватно десериализовались в LocalDateTime.

Comment: Пока решил проблему тем, что поля сделал String, а в геттере возвращаю дату в нужном формате.. только не уверен, что парсить строку при каждом доступе к полю это нормальный вариант)

Comment: Ну у меня то задача была другая - я читал из БД один раз и преобразовывал в Java объект